# Filter for modifying image on upload

Tags: plugins, filters, actions

So I'm working on building a new WordPress plugin for massive PNG compression, and I'm having a hard time finding the right filter to hook in to. I need to access the entire image so that I can open it using fopen and pass the contents to an external API. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: The plugin that you want to build [already exists](http://wordpress.org/plugins/optimus/). It's grown over years, has a good author and a very well done server setup. My recommendation: Search for a different niche.

Comment: Really neat plugin, however it doesn't operate on the same method as mine. I'm using a lossy compression API that provides upwards of 70% compression. There's probably ten other nameable plugins that do this as well, but they're all different. An answer as to which filter to use would've been much more appreciated.

Comment: Have you taken a look into the plugins source code? Everything's there. No need to serve it on a silver plate, right?